Win32OLE compatibility with 64bit
I've have number of automation scripts (written in Ruby but I think this question could apply to other languages) that use Win32OLE interface to connect to MS Office, BlueZone (Mainframe emulator) etc.
When I first wrote them I used:

32-bit version of Ruby
32-bit version of Host Software (BlueZone, MS Office)

When trying to use the 64-bit version of BlueZone with my script (installing the 32bit version works)
I am wondering is there any limitation of using win32ole interface (aka scripting language and the host software need to be 32bit) or name (win32) just a legacy and it should work with any combination and BlueZone has bug with their installation.
